# Reading json with axios and react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm a react beginner. I am trying to return the uuid and live from a json created by an api I have on my local host. I tested that and it returns:

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "80d14a1e-fd90-4d99-bca2-5d00f0b00224",
        "specific_part": {
            "uuid": "20c0481a-ee4b-4afb-a9f3-b2a1ba0a5c8a",
            "sku": "TestTest",
            "mpn": "749328571dfaA"
        },
        "customer": {
            "uuid": "c69c43ec-d5c0-4086-abc7-e93444db7cbd",
            "name": "Electronics Super Creator"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "live": false
    }
]
```

I am using the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import ListingList from "./components/ListingList";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:8000/api/v1/c69c43ec-d5c0-4086-abc7-e93444db7cbd/?format=json")
      .then(response => {

        const newListings = response.data.map(c => {
          return {
            id: c.uuid,
            live: c.live
          };
        });

        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          listings: newListings
        });

        this.setState(newState);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is returning an empty listing that looks like `{"listings":[]}` and no errors. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Also, if you have any resources for the best debugging of this stuff, I'd love to hear about them!

Comment: please do a console.log(response) first

Comment: Have you narrowed down which step the issue occurs at? Log the `response`, the `newListings` and `newState` values and see where (if anywhere) the wrong value is coming into play

Comment: It is because you are getting [] in `newListings` Try checking your API logic.

Comment: It turns out it was a problem with my API not accepting cors from the origin. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that your API may be the problem here. How are you testing it?
The only little thing that occurs to me that may cause the issue is the `/` before your query params (`?format=json`)

Depending on how you are developing your API that can consider it different from not having `/`. So try changing it:

```
// Old
// .get("https://localhost:8000/api/v1/c69c43ec-d5c0-4086-abc7-e93444db7cbd/?format=json")
// New
.get("https://localhost:8000/api/v1/c69c43ec-d5c0-4086-abc7-e93444db7cbd?format=json")
```

Making a small test, using axios on a random url and creating the data myself. Everything looks to be working.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts')
      .then(response => {
        const dummyResponse = { data: [
          {
              "uuid": "80d14a1e-fd90-4d99-bca2-5d00f0b00224",
              "specific_part": {
                  "uuid": "20c0481a-ee4b-4afb-a9f3-b2a1ba0a5c8a",
                  "sku": "TestTest",
                  "mpn": "749328571dfaA"
              },
              "customer": {
                  "uuid": "c69c43ec-d5c0-4086-abc7-e93444db7cbd",
                  "name": "Electronics Super Creator"
              },
              "quantity": 5,
              "live": false
          }
        ]};
        const newListings = dummyResponse.data.map(c => {
          return {
            id: c.uuid,
            live: c.live
          };
        });

        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          listings: newListings
        });

        this.setState(newState);
        
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```